# Visualize a random JSON object on a web page

Tags: ajax, json, user-experience

We have a "big data" service that receives requests in JSON format and returns results in JSON as well. Requests and especially responses sometime can be quite huge - up to 1GB in size ... We are logging all requests and responses and now I'm building a simple user web interface to search and show all requests we've processed.

My problem is I have a JSON which can be up to 40 levels deep and containing a lot of arrays. How can I give the user ability to drill down and explore the content?

For what it's worth the users have the latest stable version of Chrome and 64GB of RAM.

Comment: I personally use http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ but with 40 level nests it may not work so good for you. I'm posting regardless just in case it's useful for you.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://josh.zeigler.us/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/ Perhaps you could try chunking the responses into smaller sizes and send those in sequence to the user, not the entire 1GB of JSON. You could then use recursion/iteration to parse the separate chunks into usable html lists (just an example) which you could then easily search through.

Comment: That article is from 2012, my personal testing shows that now 64 bit Chrome, Firefox, IE have no problem parsing a 1GB Json.

Comment: You might try a simple tree structure like the one [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092). I'm genuinely unsure how it would perform with a large data set, but generally it is the DOM updates that cause issues, and displaying less is your friend.

Comment: Do you have access to server (backend) tech? o r are you trying to do it with JS? you can do a local server (php for example) and instead of downloading the response, you can import it to the server  (maybe using cURL), store it on a db (i.e. mysql), index it, cache it and do the search there, via query. Is that an option for you?